# How to remove element(s) from a state array variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend

I have a state variable `tasks`, which is an array of objects:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      user: "",
      text: "Finish this page",
      deadline: new Date("05/01/2022"),
      complete: true,
      priority: "high",
      project: "Gravity",
      // ToDo: Set priority based on date while creating task
    },
    {
      text: "Finish Pierian UI/UX",
      deadline: new Date("05/10/2022"),
      complete: false,
      priority: "med",
    },
    {
      text: "Finish Internship",
      deadline: new Date("05/05/2022"),
      complete: false,
      priority: "low",
    },
    {
      text: "Anaadyanta",
      deadline: new Date("05/12/2022"),
      complete: false,
      priority: "med",
    },
    {
      text: "Random task",
      deadline: new Date("05/19/2022"),
      complete: false,
      priority: "high",
    },
  ]);
```

I want to remove elements whose `complete` is `true`. I am unable to think of the correct syntax while using `setTasks`. Please help.

Comment: Please try this & share your feedback: `setTasks(prev => prev.filter(({ complete }) => complete !== true));`

Answer (score 2):

You should filter tasks and set new state:

```
const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((el)=> el.complete !== 'true');
setTasks(updatedTasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass callback inside setTasks:

```
setTask((prevTasks) => prevTasks.filter(({ complete }) => !complete));
```

The prevTasks always going to be the latest state, React insures it. You should always use callback when next state relies on previous.
Also the name of prev variable passed in callback could be whatever you choose, here I named it prevTasks.

Comment: Please consider referencing this: [React - useState - previousState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63853054/13658816).

Comment: You already did it in comment, what else am I suppose to do?