# React Modal only close when I click background or close icon?

Tags: reactjs

Here is a codepen https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-morning-ukxp2?file=/src/App.js

So I created this modal and I wrapped it with a `Background` styled component, but I can't figure out how to get the close function to only work if I only click the background or the close icon.

Right now my entire modal is wrapped with this `background` so no matter where I click it always closes. I only want it to close if I click on the `Background` or the `CloseModalButton`, but not when I click on my actual modal.

Here is my code below

```
      export const Modal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
        const animation = useSpring({
          opacity: showModal ? 1 : 0,
          transform: showModal ? `translateY(0%)` : `translateY(-200%)`
        });

        return (
          <>
            {showModal ? (
              <Background onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}>
                <animated.div style={animation}>
                  <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
                    <div>hi</div>
                    <CloseModalButton
                      aria-label='Close modal'
                      onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
                    />
                  </ModalWrapper>
                </animated.div>
              </Background>
            ) : null}
          </>
        );
      };
```

Then here is my App.js with the function to open and close the modal

```
    function App() {
      const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

      const openModal = () => {
        setShowModal(!showModal);
      };

      return (
        <Container>
          <Button onClick={openModal}>Aye what's good</Button>
          <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
          <GlobalStyle />
        </Container>
      );
    }
```

The main issue is the Background wraps my entire modal, so I need a way to only trigger my close function if the target is the actually background or the X icon, but not the actual modal itself (which is wrapped inside of the background)

Comment: Can you reproduce the output in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) ?

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but when toggling your modal, you should use the previous state of your `setShowModal`, eg: `setShowModal(prev => !prev)`.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr what's the difference between prev and just switching the state to the opposite of !showModal value?

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra I added a link to codesandbox above

Comment: @Johnxr https://stackoverflow.com/a/59990838/6245650

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr that doesn't make sense if I only need to switch between true and false. That question you linked only references a counter which has completely different values from true or false

Comment: @Johnxr I think you missed the point of the answer. Basically if we were to implement your way of updating the state, you may not get the correct current state to toggle. State updates are asynchronous so if your app gets complex and has heavy operations, the state you're fetching may not be the state you want because it hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr but how would that cause issues if a modal state should always be false until I click? Do you have an example of how it could cause issues in my example? I guess for bigger apps it could, but I'm just making a simple modal, so I'm getting confused with the link you sent

Comment: @Johnxr it can occur if you click the "Open Modal" button multiple times very quickly in succession. It's probably harder to see considering we are dealing with boolean states. That's why counter states are used to show the behavior more discretely.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr ah so I noticed if I click super fast it basically opens/closes it instantly. Wouldn't a better solution be to just disable the modal button when the modal opens up? Or is that still going to cause issues for a bigger app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to track `event.target` which gives where is has been called i.e

```
const closeModal = (event) => {
    const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    if (event.target === modal) {
      setShowModal(false);
    }
  };
<Background id="myModal" onClick={closeModal}>
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hodgkin-o77em?file=/src/components/Modal.js

Comment: I want the background to close the modal as well as the close icon. So that's why I added it both, but the problem is the background closes it no matter where I click because it wraps everything

Comment: You mean background the modal one or outside of modal?

Comment: yeah only the outside of the modal, or the close icon. if you increase the with of the screen you'll see the X icon I have

Comment: is it good to use id's with react? Do you know if that can be done with using useRef instead?

Comment: also check the console.log because there's an error that appears when you close the modal

Comment: Yeah This is what id meant for. You can do with `useRef` also but again you need some unique identifier to track from where it is click. It is basically `event delegation`. Second error is coming because you set modal state from parent. And when `showModal` is false your `Modal` component is unmounted. It's trying update the state of the modal component when its not there in dom tree. Updated my code . Check again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to event bubbling. Everytime you click any descendants of the `Background` element, the click handlers of them fires and bubbles up until it reaches the Background element firing the handler of itself. To solve this, you can either stop the propagation of the click handler of the child elements using stopPropagation() method or you can simply add **ID** to background and determine if the id matches the background only then firing the showModal method.

`<Background onClick={closeModal} id="bg">`

```
const closeModal = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'bg') {
      setShowModal(false);
    }
  };
```

It is not necessary to add id to the close button and check for the targeted button's id since clicking on the button definitely closes the modal.

Comment: is that best practice to use id's with react? isn't there a way to do the same thing with useRef?

Comment: also, there's an error in my console when I try to close the modal

Answer (score 0):

I seen an comment asking how to achieve this with useRef (included typescript types):

```
const modalBackgroundRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

const closeModal = () => {
    // Close the modal...
};

const onClickBackground = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (event.target === modalBackgroundRef.current) closeModal();
};

return (
    <div id="modal-background" tabIndex={-1} ref={modalBackgroundRef} onClick={onClickBackground}>
          // Modal goes here...
    </div>
);
```