# how can i add object in array which is in object as property (react.js )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

first off, sorry for the confusing title. I couldn't find a way to say this more clearly.

These days, I'm working on my own project and face a problem. If you can give me some
advice, it would be a huge help for me.

So, this is my State

```
const[state, setState] = useState({
    externalEvents: [
      { title: "Art 1", color: "#0097a7", id: 34432, custom: "fdsfdsfds" },
      { title: "Art 2", color: "#f44336", id: 323232 },
      { title: "Art 3", color: "#f57f17", id: 1111 },
      { title: "Art 4", color: "#90a4ae", id: 432432 },
     
      
    ]
  });
```

and this is my input tags and function

```
  <form className="todoinput"  onSubmit={addTodo} >
    <input type="text" value={title} onChange={e=>setTitle(e.target.value)} placeholder="Add event" />
    <input type="text" value={custom} onChange={e=>setCustom(e.target.value)} placeholder="detail" />
    <select>
      <option value={()=>{setColor('blue')}}>blue</option>
      <option value={()=>{setColor('orange')}}>orange</option>
      <option value={()=>{setColor('green')}}>green</option>
      <option value={()=>{setColor('purple')}}>purple</option>
    </select>
    <button  type="submit">Add todo</button>
  </form>


const addTodo = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setState([...state.externalEvents,{title:{title}, color: {color}, custom: {custom}}])
    setTitle('')
    setCustom('')
  }
```

This is what I wanted to make: I type title,custom and select color in input and select tags. And I submit it, then function is going to add new object in externalEvents(array)
I used spread to do this, but somehow it didn't work and console says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```
 <div id="external-events">
          {state.externalEvents.map((event) => (
           <div 
           className="fc-event"
           title={event.title}
           data-id={event.id}
           data-color={event.color}
           data-custom={event.custom}
           key={event.id}
           style={{
             backgroundColor: event.color,
             borderColor: event.color,
             cursor: "pointer"
           }}
           >{event.title}</div>
            ))}
      </div>
```

this is a part where map() happen, I think the reason map couldn't read property is because
I failed to send proper property to externalEvents.

thanks for reading, and your help will be appreciated.

p.s I used FullCalendar library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialized your state, it was an object with a key `externalEvents` which is an array

```js
useState({
    externalEvents: [
      { title: "Art 1", color: "#0097a7", id: 34432, custom: "fdsfdsfds" },
      { title: "Art 2", color: "#f44336", id: 323232 },
      { title: "Art 3", color: "#f57f17", id: 1111 },
      { title: "Art 4", color: "#90a4ae", id: 432432 },  
    ]
  })
```

But when you update your state, it is an array

```js
setState([...state.externalEvents,{title:{title}, color: {color}, custom: {custom}}])
```

So based on your initial state, `setState` should be as below

```js
setState({
  ...state, 
  externalEvents: [
    ...state.externalEvents, 
    {title, color, custom}
  ]})
```

Do note that `{title, color, custom}` is probably what you want, instead of `{title: {title}, xxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably inside of your `addTodo` function.

This function sets `state` to be an array. Following this, `state.externalEvents` no longer exists.
To test this, try `console.log(state)` after it has been set in `addTodo` function.

Based on your intent, here is a modification of your `addTodo` function that may solve your problem:

```js
const addTodo = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    // Use previous state, and make sure to return an object with an 'externalEvents' key as the new state
    setState((prevState) => {
        const newEvent = {} // whatever your new event is
        return { externalEvents: [...prevState.externalEvents, newEvent] }

    })
    setTitle('')
    setCustom('')
}
```

#### Further improvement

Furthermore, you can make things more simple by directly having an `externalEvents` piece of state, to remove the need for a nested `externalEvents` property inside some other state object.

For example:

```js
const [externalEvents, setExternalEvents] = useState([
      { title: "Art 1", color: "#0097a7", id: 34432, custom: "fdsfdsfds" },
      { title: "Art 2", color: "#f44336", id: 323232 },
      { title: "Art 3", color: "#f57f17", id: 1111 },
      { title: "Art 4", color: "#90a4ae", id: 432432 } 
    ])
```

If you adopt this, you would need to update your `addTodo` function once again, specifically the state update step.

Your state update step will now look like this:

```js
setExternalEvents((prevExternalEvents) => {
        const newEvent = {} // whatever your new event is
        return [...prevExternalEvents, newEvent]
    })
```

See here for more:

1. Setting state based on the previous state: [useState hook, setState function. Accessing previous state value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404819/usestate-hook-setstate-function-accessing-previous-state-value)

Comment: I agree the simplified [externalEvents, setExternalEvents], [KISS] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that you defined state as an object, with the key externalEvents, which is an array. But when you are submitting the form, in the setState function, you are setting an array, not the original shape.

I recommend you to do it like this:

```
const [externalEvents, setExternalEvents] = useState([
  { title: "Art 1", color: "#0097a7", id: 34432, custom: "foo" },
  { title: "Art 2", color: "#f44336", id: 323232 },
  { title: "Art 3", color: "#f57f17", id: 1111 },
  { title: "Art 4", color: "#90a4ae", id: 432432 },
]);
```

And in the form:

```
const addTodo = (e) => {
  ...
  setExternalEvents(prev => [...prev, {title, color, custom}])
  ...
}
```