# How add new object property while updating state in React

Tags: reactjs

Basically I want to add a new property id to the state object which is **formData** I tried the way below mention but its not working

structure of formData object

```
{
Fname : Tony
Lname : Stark
}
```

I want to Add Id property to it

```
{
id : 01
Fname : Tony
Lname : Stark
}
```

This is what I tried :

```
let arr = {...formData}
arr.id = 1
setFormData({
    arr
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setFormData((previous) => {...previous, id: 1});
```

What this will do is take the previous `formData` object and append the new value to it.

Your example could work too but you included the extra curly braces here `setFormData({arr})`.

Here's some more info on the functional version of `setState` [useState hook, setState function. Accessing previous state value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404819/usestate-hook-setstate-function-accessing-previous-state-value)

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
setFormData({...formData, id:1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setFormData({...formData, id: '01'})
```