# Basic Beginner React-Native State Question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello guys I just started learning React-Native and I have a question about state.

I was practicing this concept trying to make a button that shows how many times I've pressed it.

My plan was to make a variable called clicks which will increase by 1 each time I press it and set the clickState to clicks. This is my code.

```
    export default function App() {
  const [clickState, setClicks] = useState(0)
  let clicks = 0
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>{setClicks(++clicks); console.log(clicks)}}>
        <Text>Clicks : {clickState}</Text> 
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[this is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ86K.png)

But apparently something is wrong and my clicks value goes random between 1 and 2 each time I click it instead of increasing by 1.

So I was curious about what I was doing wrong and why the values don't increase as I expected. I would also be glad if you showed how you would implement it if there is a better way.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You want to update the current `clickSate` value not `clicks`

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't make us all wander in here to see what you're on about. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update **clickState**, no need of variable **clicks**.
Also it won't rerender if we increment state value directly, so we should increment state by taking its previous state value like shown below

```
export default function App() {
  const [clickState, setClicks] = useState(0)
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>setClicks(prevState => prevState + 1)}>
        <Text>Clicks : {clickState}</Text> 
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you explain the expression '=>' in detail? What's the difference from just saying prevState = prevState +1. Also, how does prevState work when I've never defined it?

Comment: prevState (You can name anything) is the current value of that state, and for more explanation ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59990838/10657559