# TextInput Not Updating When Buttons Are Pressed

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, calculator

I am working on a React Native application to create a calculator. I have a `TextInput` field where I want to display the input, and I'm trying to use the `showSoftInputOnFocus` property with `editable={false}` to prevent the keyboard from showing. However, even with this configuration, the content in the TextInput field is not updating when I press the number buttons.

I've set up my code to use the `showSoftInputOnFocus` property, and I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or if there's an alternative approach to make the TextInput field update when the number buttons are pressed.

Below is my code for reference:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState("")
  const handlePressBtn = (val) => {
    if (val == "C") {
      setTotal("")
    }
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>
      <TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} editable={false} style={styles.screen} value={total}></TextInput>

      <View style={styles.button_row}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("7")}>7</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("9")}>8</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("9")}>9</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.button_row}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("4")}>4</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("5")}>5</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("6")}>6</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.button_row}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("1")}>1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("2")}>2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.number_button}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text} onPress={() => handlePressBtn("3")}>3</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    </SafeAreaView >
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 20,
    gap: 10
  },
  screen: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: "right",
    fontSize: 34
  },
  button_row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    gap: 15,
    width: '90%'

  },
  number_button: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button_text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 35
  },
});
```

How to resolve this issue without using state hooks?

Comment: Why even use TextInput if it is never editable?

Comment: I want to show the result in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this happens because, the area clickable in the `<Text/>` components is small. Try to use the onPress event in the `<TouchableOpacity/>` components.

[image: demo]

https://snack.expo.dev/@hlmnd/demo

Comment: I want it to show every click. The code you provided me only gives one number for each click and does not show the complete process

Comment: of course, is your code with modifications to see the behavior when clicking on text component.

Comment: it would be better to ask what is the logic to create a calculator, which depends how you want it to work

Comment: to update the total value using the previous value, would be something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404819/usestate-hook-setstate-function-accessing-previous-state-value